# Replace closest instance of a word

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this:

```
“I’m a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan.”
```

I want to insert `<strong>` around the **"a"** in **"a diplomatic"**, but nowhere else.

What I have as input is **diplomatic** from a previous function, and I wan't to add `<strong>`to the closest instance of **"a"**.

Right now, of course when I use `.Replace("a", "<strong>a</strong>")`, every single instance of **"a"** receives the `<strong>`-treatment, but is there any way to apply this to just to one I want?

**Edit**

The string and word/char (**"a"** in the case above) could be anything, as I'm looping through a lot of these, so the solution has to be dynamic.

Comment: I might try splitting the string on "diplomatic" and using FirstIndex or LastIndex to track down the "a" you want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Would this suffice?

```
string MakeStrongBefore(string strong, string before, string s)
{
    return s.Replace(strong + " " + subject, "<strong>" + strong + "</strong> " + before);
}
```

Used like this:

```
string s = “I’m a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan.”;
string bolded = MakeStrongBefore("a", "diplomatic", s);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that “I’m a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan.” is just a random string among many and "a" is just an example. I need a dynamic way where I have an input string and and input word/char.

Comment: In your random example, would both `a` and `diplomatic` be passed to the function?

Comment: Yes, I have `a`, `diplomatic` and the string, and also index of my specific instance of `diplomatic`.

Comment: Another question: might `strong` appear at a point further back than right before `before`?

Comment: There should only be one strong before my selected word, but there will also be one after. My goal is to have `<strong>` on the words on both sides of my selected word.

Comment: Yes, but that word should be found directly before the 'diplomatic' word?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to achieve: I know the original string, *a*, *diplomatic* and *mission*, and I want `<strong>a</strong>diplomatic<strong>mission</strong>`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41731/discussion-between-allonhadaya-and-magnus-engdal)

Answer (score 0):

```
var stringyourusing = "";     
var letter = "";
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(letter));
var newText = regex.Replace(stringyourusing , "<strong>letter</strong>", 1);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in `“I’m <strong>a</strong> member of the Imperi<strong>a</strong>l Sen<strong>a</strong>te on <strong>a</strong> diplom<strong>a</strong>tic mission to Alder<strong>a</strong><strong>a</strong>n.”`?

Comment: @MagnusEngdal nope the 1 makes it only do the first occurence. I just tried it real quick to make sure and it looked like it worked.

Comment: @AlexBeisley what do you mean? How is mine not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public string BoldBeforeString(string source, string bolded, 
                               int boldBeforePosition)
{   
    string beforeSelected = source.Substring(0, boldBeforePosition).TrimEnd();

    int testedWordStartIndex = beforeSelected.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1;

    string boldedString;
    if (beforeSelected.Substring(testedWordStartIndex).Equals(bolded))
    {
        boldedString = source.Substring(0, testedWordStartIndex) + 
                       "<strong>" + bolded + "</strong>" + 
                       source.Substring(testedWordStartIndex + bolded.Length);
    }
    else 
    {
        boldedString = source;
    }

    return boldedString;
}

string phrase = "I’m a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan.";
string boldedPhrase = BoldBeforeString(phrase, "a", 41);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hei!

I've tested this and it works:

```
String replaced = Regex.Replace(
    "I’m a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan.",
    @"(a) diplomatic",
    match => "<strong>" + match.Result("$1") + "</strong>");
```

So to make it a general function:

```
public static String StrongReplace(String sentence, String toStrong, String wordAfterStrong)
{
    return Regex.Replace(
        sentence,
        @"("+Regex.Escape(toStrong)+") " + Regex.Escape(wordAfterStrong),
        match => "<strong>" + match.Result("$1") + "</strong>");
}
```

Usage:

```
String sentence = "I’m a member of the Imperial Senate on a diplomatic mission to Alderaan.";
String replaced = StrongReplace(sentence, "a", "diplomatic");
```

edit:

considering your other comments, this is a function for placing strong tags around each word surrounding the search word:

```
public static String StrongReplace(String sentence, String word)
{
    return Regex.Replace(
        sentence,
        @"(\w+) " + Regex.Escape(word) + @" (\w+)",
        match => "<strong>" + match.Result("$1") + "</strong> " + word + " <strong>" + match.Result("$2") + "</strong>");
}
```